# How do I edit mailing recipients?

Tags: mailing

I need to update the recipient list of a scheduled mailing.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do that through the UI. You're probably better off cancelling the mailing and recreating it.

If you're comfortable and familiar with the database you could edit the civicrm_mailing_recipients table for the relevant mailing, but that would be pretty fragile/risky.

Answer (score 0):

You can include and/or exclude groups as recipients of a mailing. When creating a group if you choose mailing option, it will be listed among others in autocomplete.

You can't (afaik) edit the recipient list per mailing by choosing individuals from a group.